# I can't capture the entire document on android 5.1.1 devices, just captures the area currently displayed

Tags: android, webview, screenshot, snapshot

I use `capturePicture()` method to capture the snapshot of Webview on 5.1.1 devices. But I get a bitmap only displayed the visible area of webview.

The method works fine on 4.4.0 and pre version.

Do you have the same problem?

My code as following:

```
public Bitmap captureSnapshot() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Picture snapShot = mWebView.capturePicture();
        if (snapShot.getWidth() > 0 && snapShot.getHeight() > 0) {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(snapShot.getWidth(), snapShot.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            snapShot.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        LogUtil.d(TAG, ">19");
        mWebView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        mWebView.layout(0, 0, mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(), mWebView.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWebView.getMeasuredWidth(), mWebView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        mWebView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
}
```